# VSCode Running Extremely Slow on Powerful PC: Need Help Troubleshooting

Tags: performance, visual-studio-code

I've recently noticed how it takes a minute for anything, I mean ANYTHING to run on my vscode. Even a simple line of python code. While it takes less than 5 seconds for my laptop to run it. I'm weirded out because my pc's more powerful than my laptop, and is meant to be way faster.

I updated my vscode, checked my cpu consumption and I don't really have a lot of extentions going on since I haven't even been coding for long. And I disabled my anti-virus softwares for a bit to test it out, but it still takes a minute to run. Everything else on my pc works fine and the speed's alright except vscode.

Comment: Have you tried opening menu Help > Process Explorer? (Third from bottom, ususaly.)

Comment: how fast does it run on the CL OUTSIDE VSC

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there an activity monitor for VS Code and VS Code extensions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76592863/is-there-an-activity-monitor-for-vs-code-and-vs-code-extensions)

Comment: Yeah I'e tried to check out the process explorer, it seems fine. I'm not sure what to look for there

Comment: I've also tried  to run it in the cl outside of vsc, it runs faster than that in vscode @rioV8